# What is the radius of convergence of $f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x^2-1}e^{-2t}dt$ written as a power series in a neighborhood of $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x^2-1}e^{-2t}dt$

Can $f(x)$ be written as a power series in a neighborhood of $0$?

Note that changing variables we can write $f(x)=2^{-x^2}\Gamma(x^2)$ where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. Hence we can write it as a power series, but what would be its radius of convergence?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: By recognizing the Gamma function, you know everything that there is to know. As with any other function, the radius of convergence of the power series at any point is the distance from that point to the nearest **singularity**. Do you know where they are?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't know